# Could not start the julia language server in VS Code

Tags: julia, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error in VS Code:

> Could not start the julia language server. Make sure the configuration setting julia.executablePath points to the julia binary.

In user settings I put

```
"julia.executablePath": "c:\\Program Files\\Julia\\Julia-0.5.0\\bin\\julia.exe"
```

which is a correct executable path.

Julia works without a problem in console and VS Code worked fine with older extension `0.4.2`. I've tried reinstalling both the extension and VS Code, but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS Code settings don't seem to always play nice with backslashes. Try instead single slashes, even on Windows:

```
"julia.executablePath": "c:/Program Files/Julia/Julia-0.5.0/bin/julia.exe"
```

It may, however, also be a problem with the blank in 'Program Files', in which case the legacy 8.3 filename convention could work:

```
"julia.executablePath": "c:/PROGRA~1/Julia/Julia-0.5.0/bin/julia.exe"
```

Note that you would typically have both 'C:\PROGRA~1' and 'C:\PROGRA~2' pointing to 'C:\Program Files' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)', respectively. Find the correct one from the console.

Comment: This still doesn't solve it for me. Here's what I wrote for the path: `C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Julia-1.0.0/bin/julia.exe`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, just run Julia REPL and switch to pkg mode with `]` and add LanguageServer package with `add LanguageServer` and restart vs code.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look if the 'LanguageServer' package is actually installed/somehow uninstalled, this happened to me. After manually installing it, it was all fine and dandy again.

Indexing all the packages still takes ages, though.

[image]

Comment: For any julia newbies like me reading this, enter ] to enter package mode (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-vscode/issues/405

This can happen if the VS Code extension doesn't support the current version of Julia.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that the path is pointing to the julia.exe executable inside the bin folder.

*C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Julia-0.5.0\bin\julia.exe*

because there is also another one that doesn't work.

*C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Julia-0.5.0\julia.exe*

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Julia solved this for me, I tried the previous answers

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to a SysImage you have compiled and replaced the original sys.dll file with that. Try to check the path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.3\lib\julia or any other path you have installed Julia and see if a sys.dll.backup exists there, together with a sys.dll file. Rename the sys.dll to sys.dll.old and rename the sys.dll.backup to sys.dll. Then restart julia or VS Code.